# five specific questions in general topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm stuck with those questions in topology, thanks for any replies :

1. Is the discrete topology be induced by a metric ?
2. Is the topology of a complete space induced by a metric ?
3. is The discrete topological space complete ?
4. is The discrete topological space compact ?
5. Is a compact metric space complete ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by a "complete space" if it is *not* metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the discrete metric $d(x,y) = \delta_{x,y}$ will do. (So $1$ on distinct points, $0$ on equal ones).
2. The notion "complete space" is not defined without a metric (or a uniformity), so probably you mean yes, but it's a wrongly formulated question. There are complete uniform spaces whose topology is not induced by a metric, so in general I say no.
3. The discrete topological space has a compatible complete metric: the metric defined under 1. is complete.
4. A discrete space is compact iff it is finite.
5. Yes, this is well-known. Any sequence has a convergent subsequence (in a compact metric space) and a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence converges as a whole to that same limit.